# Connect to Windows kernel from Linux computer

Tags: parallelization, remote-access

I've seen many questions regarding the connection to a Linux machine from a Windows one, but I need to do the opposite.

**Situation:** I have Mathematica on my Linux laptop (`A`) and I want to run a remote kernel on my Windows desktop (`B`) (which also has Mathematica)

**Current solution:** On `A` I have a kernel that opens in `LinkMode` so when I execute something it gives me a port and IP address of my machine. Then on `B`  I use the `LinkConnect` function that allows me to run my computations on `B`'s kernel.

**Things to improve:** I want to be able to do this automatically. One annoying part of this solution is that the numbers `N,M` that I use in the `LinkConnect` function (`LinkConnect["N@IP-address,M@IP-address",LinkProtocol->"TCPIP"`) always change, so I have to retype them every time.

The other problem is that sometimes I use parallel functions e.g. `ParallelTable[]` but using this solution doesn't allow me to execute multiple kernels on `B`.

**Questions:**  I think Mathematica comes with a way to do this connection in the background using Remote Kernels, but I don't know how to connect `A` with `B` using that.

- Is it possible to connect from Linux to Windows using Remote Kernels? if so, how?
- Will this allow me to execute parallel kernels in `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is based on the answer to [How to configure parallel remote kernels in Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8099463/2246972). The solution is:

- Install `Cygwin` on the `B` machine to have ssh. For a password-less access we need to copy the public keys of `A` to the `autorized_keys` file in `B`.
- In `A` open `Mathematica`, go to  `Preferences->Parallel->Remote Kernels` and hit `Enable Remote Kernels`. There we input the hostname of `B`, select the number of Kernels we want and check `Enable`
- Check `Use custom launch command` and paste the following text in the box:

  ```
  java -jar
  "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Java/WolframSSH.jar" 
  `3`@`1`  "/cygdrive/c/Program\\ Files/Wolfram\\
  Research/Mathematica/10.0/math.exe -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` 
  -linkname '`2`' -subkernel -noinit >& /dev/null &"
  ```

  where `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/` is the installation path of `Mathematica` in `A` and `c:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0` is the installation path in `B`.

Then writing

```
ParallelEvaluate[$MachineName]
```

outputs

```
{"xxxxx-laptop", "xxxxx-laptop", "xxxxx-pc", 
"xxxxx-pc", "xxxxx-pc", "xxxxx-pc"}
```

which corresponds to 2 local Kernels from `A` and 4 remote Kernels on `B`.

The advantage of using this method is that all these Kernels can be used for parallel computation (which answers my second question).